# LinearLayout with weight=x does not work properly on Sony Ericsson (using lib Holo Everywhere)

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-holo-everywhere

I have such layout with "scrolling_container" occupying all free space, but not more than it's required by it's inner content:

```
  <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/fancy_image"
            android:layout_height="185dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            />

        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scrolling_container"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                >
                ...

            </RelativeLayout>
        </ScrollView>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/bottom_buttons"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            >
            ...
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

To achieve that, I've added `android:layout_weight="1"`. It works perfectly on all device except older Sony Ericsson devices. On SE Experia devices ScrollView is not expanding as necessary. It's height is only ~50dp, where as I need at least 150dp.

I'm using HoloEverywhere lib as well.

Any ideas how to make HoloEverywhere LinearLayout not to ignore `android:layout_weight="1"` attribute?

Answer (score 1):

One of the solutions I've found is to use RelativeLayout, but it's not always suitable.
In this situation, I could not use RelativeLayout, so I've used stock LinearLayout implementation by adding `android.widget.` to `LinearLayout`:

```
  <android.widget.LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/fancy_image"
            android:layout_height="185dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            />

        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scrolling_container"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                >
                ...

            </RelativeLayout>
        </ScrollView>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/bottom_buttons"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            >
            ...
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.widget.LinearLayout>
```

Now `android:id="@+id/scrolling_container"` is expanding as expected. :)

Answer (score 0):

There is an open issue in Github for this: https://github.com/Prototik/HoloEverywhere/issues/543